# Gunicorn with multiple workers: Is there an easy way to execute certain code only once?

Tags: python, gunicorn, worker

If I start gunicorn with `-w 4` with an app with the content

```
print 'hello'
```

it will print four times `'hello'`. Is there some way to coordinate this in such a way that only one `'hello'` is printed? I want to do some cleanup on start which I'd like to be only executed once.

Comment: Hey @ben, did you implement Eevee's solution? Would you mind posting it?

Comment: Hey @MatthewMoisen. I edited the answer of Eevee to include my implementation.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can write a [server hook](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#server-hooks), for example `on_starting`, which will run in the master process and thus only happen once.

I think these only work if you're using a Python script for configuration, like in [their example](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/examples/example_config.py).

---

(This is the OP speaking):

What worked for me was to create a config file "my_conf.py" with the content:

```
def on_starting(server):
     print(1)
```

Then

```
gunicorn [...] -w 2 -c my_conf.py &
```

prints "1" only once on server start although two workers were specified to be used.